# Regex for deleting characters before a certain character?

Tags: regex, perl

I'm very new at regex, and to be completely honest it confounds me. I need to grab the string after a certain character is reached in said string. I figured the easiest way to do this would be using regex, however like I said I'm very new to it. Can anyone help me with this or point me in the right direction?

For instance:
I need to check the string "23444:thisstring" and save "thisstring" to a new string.

Comment: can you add sample code, inputs and desired output?

Comment: Can you provide a concrete example?

Comment: I suggest that you read a good tutorial on regular expressions.  It sounds like you need a deep understanding, not just an answer to this one question.

Comment: I agree with @AndyLester, check out this site: http://www.somacon.com/p127.php the `m/.../` operator with a group over the string you want to grab might be what you want.

Comment: I agree I need a concrete knowledge, and I need to find some tutorials. In this case I need to have this code finished before I leave work so I don't have the time to fully grasp regex right now.

Comment: I suggest that if you don't have concrete knowledge, then you can't truly say that the code is finished.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is your string:

```
I'm very new at regex, and to be completely honest it confounds me
```

and you want to grab everything after the first "c", then this regular expression will work:

```
/c(.*)/s
```

It will return this match in the first matched group:

```
"ompletely honest it confounds me"
```

Try it at the regex tester here: [regex tester](http://www.solmetra.com/scripts/regex/index.php)

Explanation:

- The `c` is the character you are looking for
- `.*` (in combination with `/s`) matches everything left
- `(.*)` captures what `.*` matched, making it available in `$1` and returned in list context.

Comment: `/.*?c(.*)/s` doesn't break if the string contain newlines, and `/^.*?c(.*)/s` can make a huge difference in performance, which can also be written as `/c(.*)/s`.

Answer (score 1):

> Regex for deleting characters before a certain character!

You can use lookahead like this

```
.*(?=x)
```

where x is a particular character or word or string.{using characters like `.`,`$`,`^`,`*`,`+` have special meaning in regex so don't forget to escape when using it within x}

---

**EDIT**

for your sample string it would be

```
.*(?=thisstring)
```

`.*` matches 0 to many characters till `thisisstring`

Comment: This is a good answer, but what if I don't know what will be after the ":". It will always be randomstring:otherrandomstring.

Comment: @Twisterz you asked for a Regex for deleting characters  before a **certain** character..you never mentioned **random** in your question..please be specific with your question..i couldn't get your question..am afraid

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one-line solution for matching everything after "before"

```
print $1."\n" if "beforeafter" =~ m/before(.*)/;
```

Edit:
While using lookbehind is possible, it's not required. Grouping provides an easier solution.

Answer (score 0):

To get the string before : in your example, you have to use `[^:][^:]*:\(.*\)`.  Notice that you should have at least one `[^:]` followed by any number of `[^:]`s followed by an actual :, the character you are searching for.